# Running spring boot angular app in Docker Tomcat container

Tags: spring-boot, docker, tomcat

I'm trying to run a spring + angular application in a Tomcat docker container. It is currently **working** on a server with Tomcat (that I did not set up) but not within my container so I think it must be an issue with my docker configuration.

Below are truncated portions of the configurations

Tomcat `context.xml`

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Context>
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>

    <Environment name="debug" type="java.lang.String" value="false"/>
    <Environment name="trace" type="java.lang.String" value="false"/>

    <Environment name="app.site.mainsite.absoluteUrl" type="java.lang.String" value="https://test.example.com"/>

    <Environment name="uiHostUrl" type="java.lang.String" value="https://test.example.com" />
</Context>
```

Spring `application-prod.yml`

```
core:
    cache:
        timeToLiveSeconds: 3600
        ehcache:
            maxBytesLocalHeap: 256M

http:
    cache:
        timeToLiveInDays: 31

spring:
    session:
        timeout: 30m # Session timeout. If a duration suffix is not specified, seconds will be used.
```

Spring `application.yml`

```
# Disable the spring security default configuration from spring-boot-actuator
management.security.enabled: true
security.basic.enabled: false

# Disable Jolokia - An http/json bridge for remote JMX access
endpoints.jolokia.enabled: false

app:
    healthCheck:
        externalUrls:

    site:
        mainsite:
            urlPrefix: /
            absoluteUrl: http://localhost:9000

core:
    cache:
        timeToLiveSeconds: 3600
        ehcache:
            maxBytesLocalHeap: 16M



management:
    endpoints:
        web:
            base-path: /admin/manage

            exposure:
                include: '*'

    endpoint:
        health:
            show-details: when_authorized


springfox:
    documentation:
        swagger-ui:
            enabled: true

swagger:
    apiDocsLocation: http://localhost:8080
    contact:
    description:
    version: 0.0.1
    includePatterns: /api/.*
    license: Apache 2.0
    licenseUrl: http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html
    termsOfServiceUrl: http://jhipster.github.io/
    title:

uiHostUrl: http://localhost:4201/
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM tomcat:9-jdk11

COPY ROOT.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war

COPY context.xml /usr/local/tomcat/conf/

ENV spring_profiles_active=prod

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

Docker command

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 test_tomcat
```

[image]

Comment: Spring and Spring Boot aren't interchangeable. Which is it? Also, have you tried unpacking the .war file in the docker image?